# sharepoint online enable retention: is it the best way to implement a document retention policy?

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, retention

I see that not all the features of document retention in sharepoint online are as active as the same feature on premise (the ability to declare it as a record, the ability to send it to another location -since there is no set location on the server-, the ability to set a custom formula on the server), is it still the way to go for a basic retention policy or is there some other feature that semi replaces/improves it?

For example send the file to another location can be achieved with Microsoft Flow.

Answer (score 0):

There is dedicated security and compliance center in O365 where you can create retention and deletion policies and apply them to the site collection/templates.

https://protection.office.com/#/retention

The retention tab under the data governance section is good place to get started.

https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Retention-in-the-Office-365-Security-Compliance-Center-2a0fc432-f18c-45aa-a539-30ab035c608c

https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Overview-of-document-deletion-policies-55e8d858-f278-482b-a198-2e62d6a2e6e5

https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Overview-of-preservation-policies-9c3b1d52-40ce-4ba3-a520-9ae0be15538a